# what is the benefit of usage uselocation hook? useLocation vs global location

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

hello I am looking for an answer what is the point of uselocation hook. I am building my first react project. I can easily reach global location object and works fine. What kind of benefit I can get if I use this hook?

Thanks.

Comment: Dupe target is about React states, but effectively the underlying concept is the same, should you use an unrestricted global variable or X in React.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question more generally, you must first understand differences such as state variables vs instance variables, or custom React hooks vs plain JavaScript functions, and so on.

Examples:

```js
const foo = "bar";
// vs:
const [foo, setFoo] = useState("bar");
```

```js
import fooFunc from "./fooFunc";
import useFooFunc from "./useFooFunc";

const foo = fooFunc;
// vs:
const foo = useFooFunc();
```

The difference in the first example is that every time you update the non-state variable foo, React will be unaware of the change and so it won't cause a re-render in your component (the component that is using the foo variable). So if you want React (React's lifecycle) to capture that change, you must use a state variable. [Check this working example on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-kowalevski-bfdse1?file=/src/TempComponent.js).

As a general rule (non-technically speaking): Everything that is somehow related to the component life-cycle must be written in *React language*.

Also about the second example, it's all the same story in essence. Nothing is wrong with fooFunc as long as you don't need to use "React stuff" in it, e.g., let's say you want to make an API call, so you will need to use the useEffect hook (otherwise things will go out of the hands of React and unexpected behavior will follow), that's why as long as fooFunc is a vanilla JavaScript function React will not allow you to use React hooks in it. This has been mentioned on [React's documentation page for Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) as well:

> Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions. Instead, you can:
>
> ✅ Call Hooks from React function components.
>
> ✅ **Call Hooks from custom Hooks**.

No back to your question, I think you can guess the answer yourself. But I will explain it once again as well. React Router is a library written for React using React, so to still keep things fully in step and under the control of these tools, you don't have to enter an *outsider* in this process. Remember you *can* use the global location object, but it's not recommended at all (unless you know what you're doing exactly).

Comment: My use-case: Capture the `location.hash` only on the first render. Is it good to use `window.location` here? Because if do `useLocation` and provide an empty dependency array, eslint shouts at me.